# Writing unit test cases for lazy loaded module angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Getting **NgModuleFactoryLoader is deprecated: the `string` form of `loadChildren` is deprecated, and `NgModuleFactoryLoader` is
part of its implementation. See `LoadChildren` for more details.** warning and not able to stub the module for testing the lazy loaded module

Below is the code

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
    import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppConfigService } from './services/appConfig.service';
    import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { NgModuleFactoryLoader } from '@angular/core';
    import { VehicleModule} from './views/vehicle/vehicle.module';
    import { DriverModule} from './views/driver/driver.module';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'admin',
    data: { preload: false },
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  { path: '', component: FrontpageComponent }];

    describe('Router: App', () => {

      let location: Location;
      let router: Router;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
      let loader: any;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot(),
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
          ],
          declarations: [AppComponent],
          providers: [AppConfigService]
        });

        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        location = TestBed.get(Location);

        loader = TestBed.get(NgModuleFactoryLoader);
        loader.stubbedModules = {
          'VehicleModule': VehicleModule,
          'DriverModule': DriverModule
        };

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

        router.resetConfig([
          {
            path: 'vehicle',
            loadChildren: 'VehicleModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'driver',
            loadChildren: 'DriverModule'
          },
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: 'VehicleModule'
          }
        ]);

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        router.initialNavigation();
      });

      it('should create APP', () => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeDefined();
      });

     it('should navigate to /student lazy loaded ,pdule', fakeAsync(() => {

        const loader = TestBed.get(NgModuleFactoryLoader);
        loader.stubbedModules = {lazyModule: StudentModule};

        router.resetConfig([
          {path: 'student', loadChildren: 'lazyModule'},
        ]);

        router.navigate(['student'])

        tick();

        expect(location.path()).toBe('/student');
      }));
    });
```

Comment: have you had any luck with replacing the deprecated code?

Answer (score 1):

loadChildren now needs a function, which will load a module:

```
{
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(mdule=>mdule.LoginModule),
```

},

For some reasons, jasmine cannot load these modules from original config, so you should reset config and give to jasmine these modules:

```
    router.resetConfig([
      {
        path: 'vehicle',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(VehicleModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'driver',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(DriverModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(VehicleModule),
      }
    ]);
```

Also, you don't need NgModuleFactoryLoader more. Remove strings:

```
    loader = TestBed.get(NgModuleFactoryLoader);
    loader.stubbedModules = {
      'VehicleModule': VehicleModule,
      'DriverModule': DriverModule
    };
```

If you need guards (for example, you need to check if canActivate works as expected), you should keep original config, but all lazy loaded modules you need too:

```
    router.resetConfig([
      ...router.config,
      {
        path: 'vehicle',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(VehicleModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'driver',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(DriverModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => Promise.resolve(VehicleModule),
      }
    ]);
```